# How to test C# void method using Microsoft Testing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest, microsoft-unit-testing

I have the following method in C#.

```
public void LoadFromDataSet(DataSet dataset)
{
      if (dataset == null)
         return;

      LoadDynamicForm(dataset);
      LoadDynamicFormFields(dataset);
}
```

I would like to unit test the first 2 lines using the Microsoft Uni testing framework. How should I go about it?

Comment: Is this your first attempt at Unit Testing?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can only validate by the missing side effects of the `LoadDynamicForm` and `LoadDynamicFormFields`.

Answer (score -1):

If LoadDynamicForm or LoadDynamicFormFields has object you can mock so you can see that the mock object function weren’t called, look for moq nugget for mor information